# Is it safe to use Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on lenovo devices?

Tags: system-installation, bios

Is it safe to use Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on Lenovo devices? Currently it is not possible to use 17.10.

Comment: Any more details?  Ubuntu 17.10 works fine on my Lenovo G710

Comment: @Panther https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.126209997.1388204850.1513956749-730430248.1497452012#Known_issues

Comment: That i a nasty looking little bug =) Thanks for the info

Comment: I see this as a pure bug report that should be closed as such. 1) No end-user workaround is possible 2) The list of of affected models can't possibly be kept up-to-date 3) A fixed iso image will be available shortly.

Comment: Well, I suppose the answer is "yes it is safe to use Ubuntu 16.04.3" , but I dont want to post that and brick someones MB, so, waiting on those more familiar with the bug to comment.

Comment: You're right @chaskes ... but OP asks whether 16.04 is safe to install - not 17.10 ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Fair point, but I had written a "Yes, but here's the bug report" answer when I decided to kill it and vtc. I still think it's better to close it.

Comment: So what's the final verdict for using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on lenovo?

Comment: Well, as @Panther already said : It **should** be safe, but who knows ? Generally it is your own decision and you always are doing everything on your own risk and that is valid for **all** systems and other installations. :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no known issues with Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04) or any other supported Ubuntu release besides Artful Aardvark (17.10) that make usually innocuous functions result in damage that you cannot undo with a full system reinstallation. The issue with Artful will likely be resolved in a week or two.

Of course, all Ubuntu distributions, just like any other good operating system, still contain more than enough means to shoot yourself in the foot and brick your computer if you do idiotic things with them.

Answer (score 0):

I 've been using Xubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad since the day it was released back in 2016. You can install the original 16.04 that's using kernel 4.4 and do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` right after the installation to fully update your system without using the HWE kernel 16.04.3 uses.

On my Thinkpad, the HWE kernel did not work well but it didn't cause any harm. I just reverted to 4.4 and uninstalled the HWE kernel.